# Getting numbered json key values

Tags: android, json

Below is the response I get from the API.

```
[{
        "claim1": [{
            "claim_no": "1",
            "claim_date": "14\/06\/2017 12:00:00 AM",
            "month_code": "1",
            "claim_amount": "8074"
        }]
    }, {
        "billing1": [{
            "claim_no": "141",
            "month_code": "1",
            "miti": "6",
            "amount": "7374",
            "paid": "7374",
            "fee1": "0"
        }]
    }, {
        "claim2": [{
            "claim_no": "26",
            "claim_date": "20\/06\/2017 12:00:00 AM",
            "month_code": "2",
            "claim_amount": "2424"
        }]
    }, {
        "billing2": []
    }, {
        "claim3": [{
            "claim_no": "40",
            "claim_date": "13\/07\/2017 12:00:00 AM",
            "month_code": "3",
            "claim_amount": "2924"
        }]
    }, {
        "billing3": [{
            "claim_no": "724",
            "month_code": "3",
            "miti": "13",
            "amount": "2924",
            "paid": "2924",
            "fee1": "0"
        }]
    }, {
        "claim4": [{
            "claim_no": "43",
            "claim_date": "09\/08\/2017 12:00:00 AM",
            "month_code": "4",
            "claim_amount": "2424"
        }]
    }, {
        "billing4": [{
            "claim_no": "402",
            "month_code": "4",
            "miti": "20",
            "amount": "5348",
            "paid": "3124",
            "fee1": "0"
        }]
    }]
```

---

I am using the aQuery jsonarray class.
I tried to get it in a JSON object, but got an error like

> jsonarray cannot be converted to jsonobject

below is my code.
This code is showing me this error

> "org.json.JSONException: No value for claim_no"

I want to get the value of claim_no

```
aq.ajax("myapiurlhere", JSONArray.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONArray>(){
            @Override
            public void callback(String url, JSONArray array, AjaxStatus status) {
                super.callback(url, array, status);
                Log.i("response:", "response:" + url + array);

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    try {

                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        bill_no = object.getString("claim_no");


                        Log.i("response:","claim: "+claim_no+" bill: "+object);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }
        });
```

I also tried the code below, but I got an error

> "claim1 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject"

```
 aq.ajax("myapiurl", JSONArray.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONArray>(){
            @Override
            public void callback(String url, JSONArray array, AjaxStatus status) {
                super.callback(url, array, status);
                Log.i("response:", "response:" + url + array);

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    try {
int mycount = i+1;
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject claimobject = object.getJSONObject("claim"+mycount);
                        claim_no = claimobject.getString("claim_no");


                        Log.i("response:","claim: "+claim_no);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: `JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`... Self explanatory. Use an array, not an object

Comment: Hint: contents inside square brackets are arrays and those inside curly braces are objects. so use `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This is an array

```
"claim1": [
```

You're getting an object

```
JSONObject claimobject = object.getJSONObject("claim"+mycount);
```

You need to get an array first

```
 JSONObject claimobject = object.getJSONArray("claim"+mycount).getJSONObject(0);
```

Also, your API is poorly structured, and `int mycount = i+1;` will likely fail because you're counting billing and claim elements at the same time

Try this instead

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    int mycount = (i/2)+1;
    try {
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked and i feel that i need changes in api. :)